# Writing a test for a Rails 3 model method that involves multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I'm new to the concept of test-driven development (and fairly new to Rails). I'm stuck with how to approach writing a test for my application.

As a backgrounder, the web app is a peer evaluation tool where individual groups are assigned surveys where they are asked to evaluate their peers. So a sample question would look like this:

```
Rate your peers on time management.
 - Peer 1: __
 - Peer 2: __
 - Yourself: __
```

How I have this set up internally is as so:

I have a `Survey` model with a `has_many` association to an `Assignment` model (which controls the visibility of surveys among groups), which acts as a join model for `Survey` and a `Group` model. In the `Group` model there is a `has_many` association with `User`s.

Because multiple groups can be assigned the same survey, I have to find out which `Group` a certain user is asked to evaluate. (So the survey would be the same, but the people that show up as in the sample above would change from user to user).

I have decided to create a method, `assignees_for_user(user)`, which would return, essentially, the user's group(s) that have been assigned to the survey.

I want to be able to unit test this method. I am using rspec and factory_girl so far. I have a few questions:

1. Is my approach even correct design-wise?
2. Should I test this? If so, I'll need to create instances for `Assignment`, `Group`, and `User`, right?
3. What's the best way I can stub/mock these instances without persisting them onto the database? Or will I have to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was more complicated than I expected (and to be honest, I guess that's why no one answered it :P)

You can use frameworks like mocha to mock things like find: [How to test ActiveRecord witout Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750959/how-to-test-activerecord-witout-rails)

I ended up using rr instead. But when it comes to activerecord associations, I still haven't found a good way to do it because I don't fully understand the ActiveRecord association proxy objects. So I guess my takeaway in all of this is, honestly, not to waste my time mocking associations in the first place: As an old adage goes, you can't unit test something that isn't your own!

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that refactoring the business logic from both the activerecord model (think of it as a database adaptor) and controller (think of it as a GUI adaptor) to plain old ruby objects (PORO) in the lib/ is the way to go.

[Hexagonal Rails by Matt Wynne](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGN4RFkhH2M), [Rails Conf 2013 Building Extractable Libraries in Rails by Patrick Robertson](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXLijKrPMv4), [Making ActiveRecord Models Thin](http://solnic.eu/2011/08/01/making-activerecord-models-thin.html) and Gary Bernhardt are good places to start.